# Como criar triggers no Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firestore

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo que precisa receber uma notificação sempre que um cliente abrir uma solicitação, mas não estou conseguindo criar uma trigger para que sempre que for aberto um novo documento o FireBase rodar essa função e me notificar. O que tentei fazer foi o seguinte:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onNewClient = functions.firestore.document("solicitacoes/{UserId}")
    .onCreate((snap,context) => {
        console.log(snap.data());
    })

exports.getCreateEvent = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
    admin.firestore().doc("solicitacoes/{userId}").get()
    .then(snapshot =>{
        const data = snapshot.data();
        response.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
});
```

A ideia é tentar criar uma maneira onde o back-end seja auto suficiente em rodar essas triggers e não precise de um evento do aplicativo para me avisar que foi criado um novo documento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma mais fácil de realizar esse tipo de trigger, ao invés de fazer tudo isso no functions é mais prático usar o .onSnapshot() para fazer isso, segue a documentação:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=pt-PT